# New for loop giving different result than old

Tags: java

Essentially i have this for loop that is supposed to loop through all the elements in an arraylist and add them into a variable named average.

```
for(int i : numbers) {average += numbers.get(i - 1); }
```

But when i run it it returns a value much larger than this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
      average += numbers.get(i)
```

Whats really interesting is that it only seems to do this with this set of numbers read from the file linked below otherwise it seems to return the same value of the other loop. But its still important to note that the reading and storing of the file into the arraylist is still the same in both trials. Any help is appreciated.

https://pastebin.com/m1Dx30qR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `for` loop, `i` is an **index** from the list, so it makes sense to use the `numbers.get` method to look-up the value in the list at that index.

In the first `for` loop, `i` is a **value** from the list, not an index; so the equivalent behaviour is to add it on directly:

```java
for(int i : numbers) {
    average += i;
}
```

I recommend reserving the name `i` for an index variable to avoid confusion; use a different name for this kind of loop where you iterate over values instead of indices.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this. You are trying to add to the index.

```
for(int i: numbers) {
    sum += i; 
}

average = (double) sum/l.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

In enhanced for loop, We shouldn't get the value based on the index. Just get the value from a variable.

**Wrong**

`for(int i : numbers) {average += numbers.get(i - 1); }`

**Correct Way**

`for(int i : numbers) {average += i; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your first for loop `int i` is acquiring each of values from the array `numbers`, you cannot control the index and is increment from 0 until max array size

example: your `numbers` contained `[8,2,4]`

by writing:

```
for (int value : numbers) {
    average += value; // 1. average = 8
                      // 2. average = 10
                      // 3. average = 14
}
```

Unless you really want to get the index using this kind of modern for loop, you have to specify it explicitly but this is pointless work.

```
int i = 0;
for (int value : numbers) {
    average += numbers.get(i);
    // do lots of other calculation using index i
    i++;
}
```